# Current Location Simulation on AppCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, location, appcode

Please correct me if this question is duplicated.

I just started using AppCode for iOS programming.

I found it very useful but issues started happening.

My application is location based app and I need to simulate the current location but with AppCode I could not seem to find that option.

I also tried to choose iOS 5 as the target platform but no joy.

Does anyone know how to do it with this IDE?

Comment: Currently AppCode doesn't support location simulation, please file a feature request http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/OC#newissue=yes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no way to simulate location right now in AppCode (well, you can only switch between locations in Simulator itself). You'd have to use Xcode for this.

But you can select iOS 5, that's not a problem. To do this you will have to edit or create new "Run configuration". Click on the combo box to the left from "Run"/"Debug" buttons. There will be "Edit Configurations" item. You can edit SDK/Debugger/Configuration for running application there.

Of course, you have iOS SDK with iOS 5.0 to be installed in your system. I believe, it's Xcode 4.2 and later.